# What exactly is a view-model?

Tags: android, viewmodel

What exactly is a view-model and in a View-ViewModel-Model pattern?

What does the word 'model' refer to?  Is the 'model' a task that has been modelled using code - for example, getting a random number and displaying it ?

And what is the significance of 'model' in ViewModel ? Does it model the visual presentation to the user like a document object model ? Any insights most welcome. Thankyou.

Comment: This is about Design Patterns. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to explain it in short in order to get the idea:

ViewModel is a class that survives orientation changes: For example look at below image:

[image]

Imagine in case you had only `mainActivity` and you rotated the phone every variable would be initialized again and you would loose everything in case you did not take any action.

The other main reason is `seperation of concerns`. This means that each class does one think. In our simple case scenario `MainActivity` would be used for UI interactivity for example button click listeners and `ViewModel` would be used for any `calculations` etc.

So `View-ViewModel-Model` is all about seperations of concerns, and writting better code which is clean and better to maintain!

For more information it is better to take your time and read from the source: [ViewModel Overview](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel)

Comment: I see, so the view-model is not concerned with

Comment: By the way I have added a link also. With What?

Comment: Thank you F Mysir. So the view-model is one model of the View - a model that does not contain any knowledge about how the View is laid out or its child UI Views - it just contains the information about the properties of 'fields' of the View which can be assigned data. So the view-model is a bit like a list of variables or a table of variables? Is this correct ?

Comment: I am beginning to understand the significance of the word 'model' and because as you say the the data in a View does not survive device configuration change, the view-model can be used to repopulate the View with the data it held.

Comment: Yes exactly this is one of the reasons! Also imagine you started a background thread in MainActivity, and you rotate the phone - problems... In ViewModel it would run smoothly. Try to search on YouTube for `Android Architecture`. There you could find speaches that explain the big picture :)